# jQuery Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined (anonymous function)

Tags: jquery

All,
I'm getting an error from some of my code that I downloaded. Here is the code:

```
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* wl_Alert v 1.1 
/* description: Handles alert boxes
/* dependency: jquery UI Slider, fadeOutSlide plugin
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------*/


$.fn.wl_Alert = function (method) {
var args = arguments;
return this.each(function () {

    var $this = $(this);


    if ($.fn.wl_Alert.methods[method]) {
        return $.fn.wl_Alert.methods[method].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(args, 1));
    } else if (typeof method === 'object' || !method) {
        if ($this.data('wl_Alert')) {
            var opts = $.extend({}, $this.data('wl_Alert'), method);
        } else {

            var opts = $.extend({}, $.fn.wl_Alert.defaults, method, $this.data());
        }
    } else {
        $.error('Method "' + method + '" does not exist');
    }


    if (!$this.data('wl_Alert')) {

        $this.data('wl_Alert', {});

        //bind click events to hide alert box
        $this.bind('click.wl_Alert', function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            //Don't hide if it is sticky
            if (!$this.data('wl_Alert').sticky) {
                $.fn.wl_Alert.methods.close.call($this[0]);
            }

            //prevent hiding the box if an inline link is clicked
        }).find('a').bind('click.wl_Alert', function (event) {
            event.stopPropagation();
        });
    } else {

    }
    //show it if it is hidden
    if ($this.is(':hidden')) {
        $this.slideDown(opts.speed / 2);
    }

    if (opts) $.extend($this.data('wl_Alert'), opts);
});

};

$.fn.wl_Alert.defaults = {
speed: 500,
sticky: false,
onBeforeClose: function (element) {},
onClose: function (element) {}
};
$.fn.wl_Alert.version = '1.1';


$.fn.wl_Alert.methods = {
close: function () {
    var $this = $(this),
        opts = $this.data('wl_Alert');
    //call callback and stop if it returns false
    if (opts.onBeforeClose.call(this, $this) === false) {
        return false;
    };
    //fadeout and call an callback
    $this.fadeOutSlide(opts.speed, function () {
        opts.onClose.call($this[0], $this);
    });
},
set: function () {
    var $this = $(this),
        options = {};
    if (typeof arguments[0] === 'object') {
        options = arguments[0];
    } else if (arguments[0] && arguments[1] !== undefined) {
        options[arguments[0]] = arguments[1];
    }
    $.each(options, function (key, value) {
        if ($.fn.wl_Alert.defaults[key] !== undefined || $.fn.wl_Alert.defaults[key] == null) {
            $this.data('wl_Alert')[key] = value;
        } else {
            $.error('Key "' + key + '" is not defined');
        }
    });

}
};

//to create an alert box on the fly
$.wl_Alert = function (text, cssclass, insert, after, options) {
//go thru all
$('div.alert').each(function () {
    var _this = $(this);
    //...and hide if one with the same text is allready set
    if (_this.text() == text) {
        _this.slideUp($.fn.wl_Alert.defaults.speed);
    }
});

//create a new DOM element and inject it
var al = $('<div class="alert ' + cssclass + '">' + text + '</div>').hide();
(after) ? al.appendTo(insert).wl_Alert(options) : al.prependTo(insert).wl_Alert(options);

//return the element
return al;
};
```

Has anyone seen this type of error before? How would I resolve something like this? Thanks for any advice you have!

Comment: Your code is executing before jQuery is loaded. Make sure that the jQuery library executes before the above code.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas I don't believe that is the case. The jQuery objects are being loaded before this file when I view the source.

Comment: On which line is the error thrown? Which expression exactly is the cause?

Comment: @ŠimeVidas It is on this line: $.fn.wl_Alert = function (method) {

Comment: So, `$` is undefined. That means that jQuery didn't load correctly (or some other script corrupted the `$` variable). That's all I can say, based on the information you're providing currently.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas  I am using Wordpress which has a noconflict with jQuery. Do I need to do something to the above code to make that a non issue?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Try this:

```
(function ( $ ) { 

    // put all that "wl_alert" code here   

}( jQuery ));
```

So, the `$` variable is apparently corrupted, but the `jQuery` variable should still refer to the jQuery object. (In normal circumstances, both the `$` and `jQuery` variables refer to the (same) jQuery object.)

Instead of having to replace the `$` name with the `jQuery` name in your entire code, you can simply use an [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) to alias the name manually. So, the outside-variable `jQuery` is aliased with the `$` variable inside the function.

Here's a simple example to help you understand this concept:

```
var foo = 'Peter';

(function ( bar ) {

    bar // evaluates to 'Peter'

}( foo ));
```

Comment: No publique solo una linea de código, para las personas que no son tan expertas. -1

Comment: how can add this inside the cdn?

Answer (score 89):

try to call jQuery library before bootstrap.js

```
<script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Does it matter when popper.js is included?

Comment: Thanks a Lot for this one

Answer (score 33):

If you get *Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined*, the problem may be you loading libraries in **wrong order.**

For example:

You should load **bootstrap.js** first and then load *bootstrap.js* libraries.

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap3-dialog/1.34.7/js/bootstrap-dialog.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 11):

Import the **jquery CDN** as a first

(e.g)

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 6):

> I fixed it by added the *jquery.slim.min.js* after
>   the *jquery.min.js*, as the Solution Sequence.

**Problem Sequence**

```
<script src="./vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="./vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

**Solution Sequence**

```
<script src="./vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="./vendor/jquery/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="./vendor/jquery-easing/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: if i understand correctly, `slim` is a subset of the full library. basically, you just included the full library, then the `slim` version immediately after.

Answer (score 5):

**Ha ha ha Funny it's a simple mistake for me**

I got **`async`** on my **jquery** library  call. Just remove it and I got solution.

```
<script async src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
```

**TO**

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
```

**Why it did this kind of behave:** I got  documentation on W3schools [LINK](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_async.asp)

**Definition and Usage async**

The async attribute is a boolean attribute.

When present, it specifies that the script will be executed asynchronously as soon as it is available.

**Note:** The async attribute is only for external scripts (and should only be used if the src attribute is present).

**Note:** There are several ways an external script can be executed:

**1.** **If async is present:** The script is executed asynchronously with the rest of the page (the script will be executed while the page continues the parsing)

**2.** **If async is not present and defer is present:** The script is executed when the page has finished parsing

**3.** **If neither async or defer is present:** The script is fetched and executed immediately, before the browser continues parsing the page

Answer (score 3):

You can use noConflict function:

```
var JJ= jQuery.noConflict(); 
JJ('.back').click(function (){
    window.history.back();
});
```

Change all $ to JJ.

Comment: I used the noConflict function as well, but using $ as the variable so I didn't have to go through my code and change it.

var $ = jQuery.noConflict();

Answer (score 3):

When I used Electron + Angular such order helped me to solve problem

```
  <script src="./assets/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="./assets/js/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="./assets/js/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="./assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: why are you using jquery.min.js and jquery.slim.min.js together?

Answer (score 2):

I too had the "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined" with:

```
$.fn.circleType = function(options) {

CODE...

};
```

But fixed it by wrapping it in a document ready function:

```
jQuery(document).ready.circleType = function(options) {

CODE...

};
```

Answer (score 1):

This error might also occur if you have require.js ([requirejs](http://requirejs.org/)) implemented and you did not wrap some lib that you are using inside

`define(['jquery'], function( jQuery ) { 
  ... lib function ...
});`

NOTE: you do not have to do this if this lib has AMD support. You can quickly check this by opening this lib and just ctrl+f "amd" :)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I did it this way

//note that I added jquery separately above this

```
<!--ENJOY HINT PACKAGES --START -->
<link href="path/enjoyhint/jquery.enjoyhint.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="path/enjoyhint/jquery.enjoyhint.js"></script>
<script src="path/enjoyhint/kinetic.min.js"></script>
<script src="path/enjoyhint/enjoyhint.js"></script>  
<!--ENJOY HINT PACKAGES --END -->
```

and it works

Comment: I came for looking enjoyhint fix, and found this by chance. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when using bootstrap-datewidget and i loaded jquery in the header instead of loading it at the end of the body and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with MarsPeople regarding loading libraries in the wrong order. My example is from working with owl.carousel.

I got the same error when importing jquery after owl.carousel:

```
<script src="owl.carousel.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
```

and fixed it by importing jquery before owl.carousel:

```
<script src="jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="owl.carousel.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope it helps someone on earth. In my case jQuery and $ were available but not when the plugin bootstrapped so I wrapped everything inside a setTimeout.
Wrapping inside setTimeout helped me fix the error:

```
setTimeout(() => {
    /** Your code goes here */

    !function(t, e) {

    }(window);

})
```

Answer (score 0):

in my case I am sending undefine variable to ajax data property, that's why ajax is not sending.