# JQuery compatibility & WordPress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

The JQuery based code that an html theme I purchased refers to the `JQuery` object with the shorthand, that is `$`.

WordPress however uses `Jquery` object as `JQuery` - for compatibility reasons.

I want to stick to the WordPress way of doing this and change that theme's code to be compatible with WordPress.

Is there a way to turn that theme's javascript code to work with JQuery object? 
Just to be more specific, I'll give you an example;

Consider the following JavaScript code which takes care of `Equal Height Columns` using some JQuery magic

```
/* __________________ Equal Heights __________________*/
$.fn.eqHeights=function(a){var f={child:false};var a=$.extend(f,a);var d=$(this);if(d.length>0&&!d.data("eqHeights")){$(window).bind("resize.eqHeights",function(){d.eqHeights()});d.data("eqHeights",true)}if(a.child&&a.child.length>0){var c=$(a.child,this)}else{var c=$(this).children()}var g=0;var b=0;var e=[];c.height("auto").each(function(){var h=this.offsetTop;if(g>0&&g!=h){$(e).height(b);b=$(this).height();e=[]}b=Math.max(b,$(this).height());g=this.offsetTop;e.push(this)});$(e).height(b)};
```

Also consider the following init that goes with that section.

```
/* ________  equal heights __________________*/

$(document).ready(function () {
   $('.equalHeights').eqHeights();
});
```

Now... What do I do where so that the above code becomes compatible with WordPress?

I know I have to insert the `JQuery` string in some key place(s) somewhere above, but not sure exactly where..

This codex page (link below) is a great resource but still, I cannot figure out how that's done.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_Wrappers

Actual code for http://bombdiggitydesign.com/crisp-2/Crisp-warm/hero-equal-height-columns.html is here http://bombdiggitydesign.com/crisp-2/Crisp-warm/assets/js/custom.js ( just search for EqualHeights).

I just copied a small section above to make my point rather than making you deal with her huge custom.js. I think the sections I grabbed is good enough to understand how that's done.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this question is in the following stackoverflow url:

[jQuery Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined (anonymous function)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10807430/jquery-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-fn-of-undefined-anonymous-fun)

But to bring it home, here is what I needed to do:

wrap the main code in the custom.js like this;

```
(function ( $ ) { 

    // all that $ based code goes here... 

}( jQuery ));
```

In other words,

go to the custom.js file ( which is located at http://bombdiggitydesign.com/crisp-2/Crisp-warm/assets/js/custom.js ) and add this to the top

```
(function ( $ ) {
```

and this to the bottom

```
}( jQuery ));
```

and saved the file. No extra work was needed.

This is a holistic solution cause with only 2 lines of code, you not only take care of the EqualHeights section I was referring to but also the rest of the whole she-bang. They now all are  compatible with WordPress.

Hope it helps someone. - which I am sure will.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was an incompatibility with the latest version of jQuery. Add this to your theme's functions.php as a temporary workaround until the plugin is fixed:

```
function thethe_fix() {
    wp_deregister_script('jquery');
    wp_enqueue_script("jquery", 
        "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js", array('json2'),
        '1.8.3');
}
add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'thethe_fix', 20 );
```

Note that this will fix your site onto version 1.8.3 of jQuery, which might not be a good thing long term.