# jQuery easyui Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'options' of undefined

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, jquery-easyui

I am new in jQuery. I am using a **easyui** plugin to use 'tab' functionality in my ASP.NET project. In my project, there are total two tabs on my current page and I am rendering a jQgrid on 2nd tab. When I click on 2nd tab, its  render grid without any problem but its giving an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'options' of undefined

and point this error in `jquery.easyui.min.js` and that line is as follows:

```
function _290(_291){
  var opts=$.data(_291,"tabs").options; <== Error is on this line 
  var cc=$(_291);
  if(opts.fit==true){
      var p=cc.parent();
      p.addClass("panel-noscroll");
      if(p[0].tagName=="BODY"){
      $("html").addClass("panel-fit");
  }
}
```

Is this error because of easyui or any my programming mistake. Is anyone know how to solve this problem??

**UPDATE:** My code for tab functionality
After showing above error, I found that debugger showing an error as a 'anonymous' function on following line where I shown an arrow

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  PopulateParcelType(); <== Here (2)
  PopulateItemBatch();

  $('#divIGPTabs').tabs({
    border: false,
    fit: false,
    onSelect: function (title, index) {
        LoadInwardGPTabs();
    }
  });
 });

 $(window).load(function () {
    $("#divIGPTabs").tabs('resize'); <== Here (1)
    $('#divIGPTabs').height('100%');
 });
```

Comment: did you have a look at this already? [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10807430/jquery-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-fn-of-undefined-anonymous-fun](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10807430/jquery-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-fn-of-undefined-anonymous-fun)

Comment: Can you post your tab code and/or a demo on jsfiddle?

Comment: I don't know How to use jsfiddle.. but I will post my tab code here.. is this fine??

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Iw4f-yRf7RU or https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zrWkRHSK6A8 for example