# jqtree uncaught error in console

Tags: jquery, jqtree

I could not replicate this issue in jsfiddle, but in my dev environment something is breaking the code. 
I have duallistbox, ckeditor 4.4.3, jquery 1.9.1 and jquery ui 1.10.3

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefinedSimpleWidget.register @ tree.jquery.js:225411../drag_and_drop_handler @ tree.jquery.js:3242s @ tree.jquery.js:1e @ tree.jquery.js:1(anonymous function) @ tree.jquery.js:1
```

Comment: Hard to say, maybe your code is executing before jQuery is loaded. Make sure that the jQuery library executes before the code triggering the error

Comment: Did you see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10807430/jquery-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-fn-of-undefined-anonymous-fun

Comment: @whitelettersinblankpapers I think our theme uses `scriptaculous` and its blowing the jqtree. I renamed `$.fn` to `jQuery.fn`, this resolved that error, it shows error in another place, looks like where ever there is a call to dom element using `$`, its breaking the code $(node.element)
`$(position_info.target);
return $(li)
$.extend
$.Event
$(document)
return $(el)`

Answer (score 0):

wrapped the whole code in below code fixed the issue

```
(function($) {
   // jqtree code
}(jQuery));
```