# Webpack: how to use the library depends on another library as module?

Tags: webpack

To make `jquery.selection` library work, `jquery` library must be loaded, because `jquery.selection` has the [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) (Immediately-Invoked Function Expression) which depends on `jquery`.  Normally, we need to do it like

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js">
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.selection.min.js">
```

However, what if we use `webpack` and want to add `jquery.selection` as module?

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import 'jquery.selection';
```

Although `Webpack` will be executed without errors, in Chrome console the following error message will appear:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined
```

Because we should not to tamper in the library, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10807430/jquery-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-fn-of-undefined-anonymous-fun) solution may not be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery needs to be global. U should use [expose-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/expose-loader) to make it global.

if u use **webpack v1**, add to webpack loader

```
{
   test: require.resolve("jquery"), 
   loader: "expose-loader?$!expose-loader?jQuery"
}
```

if u use **webpack v2**, add to webpack rule

```
{
   test: require.resolve('jquery'),
   use: [{
      loader: 'expose-loader',
      options: 'jQuery'
   },
   {
      loader: 'expose-loader',
               options: '$'
   }]
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! ... the output modules count becomes near two times. Is it OK for performance?