# fullcalendar cannot read property 'fn' of undefined

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I embedded `fullcalendar.min.js` to my project, but I get this error:

> error log show "Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined"

See picture below.

I checked this issue, it's suggested to use `jQuery 2.0.0+`, and for sure I use `jQuery v3.3.1`, but it does not help to solve problem.

[image]

Comment: what version of fullCalendar? What version of momentJS? Did you include these files in the correct order (as per fullCalendar documentation)? Did you make sure all the files were loaded before trying to execute your calendar script? We can only guess without seeing your code. See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/installation, https://fullcalendar.io/docs/initialization and https://fullcalendar.io/support, and/or take a look at the source code of one of the many demos shown on the site, to see how it's done.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined (anonymous function)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10807430/jquery-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-fn-of-undefined-anonymous-fun)

Comment: @ADyson I have used a demo version and modified it with fillcalendar 3.9.0 (momentsjs 2.221, jquery 3.3.1, jquery-ui 1.12.1), it worked. But when I moveed to different env  with same code and document, i got error, thanks.....

Comment: Then you must have some difference in your environment compared to the demo. I don't know what that difference is because I can't see either the demo or your other environment. You'll have to find the difference, or if you can make a CodePen which produces the error, then maybe I can tell you where it went wrong.

Answer (score 29):

That's because you have to load moment.js before fullcalendar.js!

Answer (score 10):

The documentation should include a reference to moment.js

**https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js**

then the fullcalendar.js references:

`https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.9.0/fullcalendar.min.js
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.9.0/fullcalendar.min.css
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.9.0/fullcalendar.print.css`

Comment: for my case, moment.js was creating the problem. thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

For me adding `momentjs` DIDN'T WORK. but `changing the cdn` worked:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/fullcalendar@5.1.0/main.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/fullcalendar@5.1.0/main.min.css" />
<div id="calendar"></div>
<script>
  var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
  var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    initialView: 'dayGridMonth'
  });
  calendar.render();
</script>
```