# FullCalendar : Cannot read property 'fn'

Tags: asp.net, webforms, fullcalendar

Need a help. I'm running a fullcalendar plugin in asp.net webforms. It shows me this error :

```
fullcalendar.js:1259 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined
at Object.<anonymous> (fullcalendar.js:1259)
at __webpack_require__ (fullcalendar.js:35)
at Object.<anonymous> (fullcalendar.js:4554)
at __webpack_require__ (fullcalendar.js:35)
at Object.<anonymous> (fullcalendar.js:1759)
at __webpack_require__ (fullcalendar.js:35)
at Object.<anonymous> (fullcalendar.js:12379)
at __webpack_require__ (fullcalendar.js:35)
at fullcalendar.js:78
at fullcalendar.js:81
```

I'm guessing that it might be my scripts arrangement and i think i have arranged them correctly in BundleConfig :

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/fullcalendar").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.3.3.1.js",
                        "~/Scripts/moment.min.js",
                        "~/Scripts/fullcalendar.js"));
```

And this is in the masterpage :

```
<asp:PlaceHolder runat="server">
    <%: Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr") %>
    <%: Scripts.Render("~/bundles/fullcalendar") %>
</asp:PlaceHolder>
```

Much Thanks !

Comment: do you have check this answers here ? : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50289327/fullcalendar-cannot-read-property-fn-of-undefined

Comment: You had already used proper script order. Can you provide scripts ordering inside `modernizr` bundle?

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto I haven't add anything inside modernizr bundle.

Comment: check your network tab to ensure all the scripts are loading correctly (200 ok status for every script requested), and check your bundles and page code to ensure that you haven't done anything silly like include jQuery or momentJS twice or something.

Comment: Also, what version of fullCalendar, and what version of momentJS are you using? We can't tell...but you need to make sure they are compatible as per https://fullcalendar.io/support